# How to run JMeter 5.x script every 5 minutes for one hour without using jenkins

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

How to run JMeter script, every 5 minutes for one hour without using Jenkins. Perovsuly use schedulers do that but in latest JMeter not supporting schedules.
Appreciate help on this

Answer (score 1):

You can amend your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) settings to run the Samplers for 1 hour followed by 5 minutes delay

[image]

The delay can be introduced using [Flow Control Action Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) or [Constant Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer) or both.

---

If you need rather separate script executions you can use your operating system scheduling mechanisms like [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) or [Linux Crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, used same suggested  by you and  used Flow Control Action Sampler